# How to set up RealVNC with a professional subscription on Ubuntu?

Tags: server, vnc, 21.04

Their documentation says that I need to install and log in to license it, but after installing it there's no place to log in and it just gives the error "VNC Server in User Mode requires an Enterprise subscription"

Here's what I see:

[image]

[image]

The tray options are: Open, Information Center, Options (greyed out), Technical Support, About, and Stop VNC Server. I'm running the 20.4 LTS.

How do I set up VNC Server on Ubuntu?

Comment: Pronouns are confusing: "***Their** documentation*", "*license **it***", "***it** just gives an error*". Links or nouns, please, to clarify whomever or whatever you might be referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Run the script found here: https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003474572-How-do-I-get-started-with-VNC-Connect-on-Linux-#installing-vnc-server-0-2

In my case, I have a professional subscription, so I:

Uninstalled VNC Server

Reinstalled it, but didn't run it

Ran the script, option 2 at first to get it into Service Mode

Then continued the script with option 1 to license it.

Happy vncing!